# Tizen Native Service: Unable to access Location and Heart Rate at the same time

Tags: c, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app, tizen-studio

I'm working on a Hybrid Application (Web UI + Native Service) for Samsung Wearable 4.0. I've implemented the code for getting [Heart Rate](https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/accessing-heart-rate-monitor-hrm-sensor-data-native-applications) and [Location](https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/location-sensors/location) data from the Native Service. I've also set the application to [continuously get the data in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752776/is-it-possible-to-keep-tizen-application-alive-non-stop/50814115#50814115) as well. The **problem is that I'm getting the location only and not the heart rate.**

- If I stop the location manager, I get the heart rate.
- If I start both the location manager and the heart rate sensor, Most of the times I get the location data only, sometimes I get a few heart rate data points after 40-50 location data points.

I haven't seen any such problem posted so far. I've checked my code but it *seems to be correct* as per the sample codes available for Tizen application development.

If I skip one module (Location or Heart Rate) the other one works fine which makes me believe that somehow location sensor stops the heart rate sensor ?

Comment: Hello, have you used emulator or real device? could you let us know test environment? thanks in advance!

Comment: I've used both the Emulator and the Device. On Emulator the code worked fine. On wearable device `RM-800` I was facing this behavior. I've solved the problem by separating the services. Now I am launching two Services for Location and Heart Rate.