# Tizen Native Service Application Not Responding

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I'm working on a Hybrid Application (Web UI + 2 Native Services) for Samsung Wearable OS 4.0,  I've set my service applications to [continuously get the data in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752776/is-it-possible-to-keep-tizen-application-alive-non-stop/50814115#50814115) as well. I'm using these services for the data collection, One for the Location and other for Heart Rate, Gyroscope and Accelerometer. Both Services get the data and send the JSON format to the Server API using CURL [method](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_perform.html). The **problem is that the Heart Rate Service stops responding if the WiFi Signals/Network is not available for some time.**

- I've included sensors and background-network as the application back-ground category.
- I've checked that there's no *crash-info* generated in the application directory on device.
- When I connect the device to my machine, the log file shows that everything was running smoothly and the Service never woke up after the sleep. (I'm using Sleep method to make delays in data collection)

I have seen some similar problems posted on SO and other forums but unfortunately nothing helped me in this case.

The **weird part** is that other Service (being used for Location data collection) is running smoothly despite of the fact that both the Services use same methods for parsing the JSON and then posting it to the Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try several things to solve this problem.

- Check if this problem happens even without using CURL. We need to know if this is an issue independent of using curl.
- Try using CURL in another thread, not the main thread

also, would you describe more details? If you attach implementation details or logs etc, it will help to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the CURL thing. Now I can see that CURL is not supposed to be used in the main thread :)
But the weird thing is that the *Location Data Collection Service* is also using CURL in the main thread and that is working perfectly fine (as expected).